# Integration between HP ALM and Appium

Tags: selenium, automation, integration, appium, alm

Is it possible to establish a connection between HP ALM and Appium to automate the test execution in ALM?

Comment: could you please explain this further more? What kind of test cases you are managing in HPALM? QTP based automatic tests you want to execute?

Comment: I have written few test cases to automate using Appium, now I want to automate the test execution also from HP ALM. Is there a way establish a connection between ALM and Appium for automatic test execution. I am using Appium tool for mobile test automation.

Comment: Do you want to execute tests in ALM or Appium? I know the way to execute it automatically in HP ALM based on some external trigger. It will be good if you draft use case/scenario of this execution.

Comment: I want to execute tests in ALM , and the tests are Mobile automation scripts which will be run using Appium. cases or scenarios of the execution will be code based. but is there any way to link the ALM Test execution with Appium or Selenium?

Comment: I can provide you details of how ALM automated tests can be triggered using code. If your automated scripts are able to communicate with Appium you can trigger externally.

Comment: ok. Thank you. Please provide me the details.

Comment: Basically let me explain what I need clearly.. If I click on Run on a Test case in ALM, that should trigger my code and after execution of the code the Test case result needs to be updated accordingly. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Yes, automated test cases are meant to do the same thing. You can create QTP/UFT based test cases that can call external services/logic and based on the out come it write back results automatically. There are lots of tutorial which teaches this. http://automated-360.com/web-services/web-services-and-uft-testing-soap-web-services/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You will have to use a different API for ALM. You've got 2 ways to achieve this:

1. Using HP-ALM OTA API (OTA API Reference: [Click here)](http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/api_refs/ota/webframe.html) 
   Pros:
   a.) OTA API is a huge C# API with enormous variety of functionalities which can be used. 
   b.) Object Based API. Most programmers can work easily use it.
   Cons:
   a.) Platform dependent. Need to register the OTA COM Client .dll in your local system (Windows) to use it.
   b.) HP might migrate entirely to REST API in future and stop support/updates for COM API.
2. Using HP-ALM REST API (REST API Reference: [Click here)](http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html#General/Overview.html%3FTocPath%3D_____1) 
   Pros: 
   a.) Platform independent. Does not require any client-side software to be installed/registered. Post HTML requests to a server and process the XML-formatted results.
   b.) API of the future. HP might migrate entirely to REST API in future. 
   Cons:
   a.) It primarily focuses only on simple CRUD operations of core entities in the client (CRUD = create, read, update, delete).
   b.) Not all ALM functionalities exposed through this API.

You can also have a look at my git repo: [myGitRepo](https://github.com/sahildarOck). Have got 2 projects implemented using OTA COM API. Both have got a UI with functionalities to achieve several day to day manual tasks performed in ALM. There are several enhancements I am currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Agiletestware Bumblebee](https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/bumblebee-docs/en/latest/qa-frameworks/appium/). It provides integration with Appium and Selenium on a source code level with a set of Java annotations.
See the detailed guide [here.](https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/bumblebee-docs/en/latest/qa-frameworks/appium/)

Disclaimer: I'm developer of Bumblebee